# Getting a date string from POSIX date/time in R

Tags: r, date

I needed the date part of a POSIXct object as a string. I planned storing these strings in a character col of a data frame. When I use

```
as.Date(mydatetime, tz="")
```

I get

```
#[1] "2014-01-02"
```

but when I print the dataframe element where I stored the date

```
print(index$date[1])
```

I get an integer like (not the same date...)

```
#[1] "11323"
```

I later need to output the dataframe as an Excel file. How do I get the character string? I extensively searched the standard R help to no avail. Nothing similar in stack overflow.

Comment: Why do you need to print?  You can use `write.csv(index, 'yourfile.csv')`

Comment: Try `as.character(index$date[1])`.

Comment: `as.character(as.Date("2014-01-02"))` converts the `Date` to `string`. If you want to separate year month day.Then use `strsplit`